# What are the gait related involuntary muscular diseases?

Tags: musculoskeletal-system, gait-walk-abnormalities

Pathology that affects gait (manner of walking) is largely associated with disorders that affect the voluntary muscles (skeletal muscle), e.g., fibromyalgia and Trendelenburg's sign.

Are there any involuntary muscular diseases that affect the gait of a person?

Also, does sarcopenia and Pompe disease (gait related muscular disorders) affect involuntary muscles?